# Is it possible to unupvote If the edit wasn't OP made?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

As the title already says all:
Is it possible to unupvote, if the edit wasn't OP made?
i.e. An suggested edit of anyone and it got approved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Any edit to the post at all allows votes made before the edit to be revoked.

If someone else fixes the problems with the post, or introduces problems with the post, a reader may wish to alter their vote.

Comment: kind of unfair, isn't it? for example i ask some simple stuff, other persons are destroying it and i get downvoted for it?

Comment: @Zaibis And if someone edits the post to make it incorrect?  Wouldn't it be unfair to prevent someone from changing their vote accordingly?  If editors are vandalizing your post flag for mod attention.

Comment: @Zaibis Well, if someone edits the post to be no longer worthy of an upvote, that edit shouldn't be approved (and hopefully a 2ker won't ruin a post like that)

Comment: The better why would be of letting audience edits even after approving get respected by vote changes.

Comment: @StephenTG Not necessarily, for several reasons: 1) it could be a 2k+ user 2) they could be editing in the viewpoints of the OP as stated in comments, in which case such an edit would be valid 3) they may not be changing the post, they could just be making it more clear what it's really saying, if, as a result of this improved clarity, you realize it was always wrong...

Comment: @Servy 1) I mentioned that hopefully a 2Ker wouldn't be making an edit that makes the post worse 2) In this case, it's the OP's own viewpoints garnering the vote change, so fairness shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @Zaibis if someone makes a bad edit to your post you can roll it back. This is something that rarely happens. What is far more common is that you get downvotes for a poorly written question or answer, someone else fixes your errors, and you go on to get upvotes for it.

Comment: ah ok, didn't knew about that rollback feature.

Comment: @Zaibis Also, even though the rep is tied to your user account, votes are for the post, not the individual, so you aren't getting downvoted, the post is.  Votes are supposed to show how useful or helpful a post is.  If wouldn't be worth much if you couldn't downvote a bad post just because of who edited it.